# I'm making a collapsible list of categories, I need that when click in a item the rest of items are collapse

Tags: reactjs, recursion

I'm build spend management app
I have a component that show the categories spend list
the category list component is an object with array of category,

the category list component receive by props an object of the type Category

I am trying that when the user clicks on a child node, the rest of the nodes that do not belong to the same branch change the isVisible state to false so that they are hidden

```
type Category = {
    id: string;
    parent: string;
    name: string;
    children: Category[];
}

type Props = {
  node: Category
}

const CollapsibleList = ({ node }: Props) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)
  const toggleVisible = () => setIsVisible(!isVisible)

  return (
    <List>
      <Item
        isSelected={isVisible}
        onClick={toggleVisible}>
        {node.name}
      </Item>
      {isVisible && node.children?.map(childrenNode =>
        <CollapsibleList
          key={childrenNode.id}
          node={childrenNode}
        />
      )}
    </List>
  )
}

export default CollapsibleList
```

I have tried everything any ideas are helpful
This is my first post, any criticism is welcome.

I leave a link to codesandbox [minimal working sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-antonelli-cu6cng?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: What do you mean by control the state? What behavior are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I updated the question.
I am trying that when the user clicks on a child node, the rest of the nodes that do not belong to the same branch change the isVisible state to false so that they are hidden.
I think I'm going to use redux adding a prop on the category object so that it controls the isvisible state.